# Weighting F1 score in a way to preference FP minimization over FN

Tags: classification, boosting, binary-data

We have a use case where we are using F1 score to optimize threshold selection for a binary classifier. In this use case however, FP's present a higher risk impact than FN. We'd like to consider a way to modify the conventional F1 score formula in such a way that its calculation weights FP as a higher impact than FN.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where or how in F1-score calculation we might weight the FPs at a say 20% higher than FNs?

Happy to take feedback on any of the above statements.

Comment: I would suggest you alternatively look at separating your concerns. (a) Create a model that yields predicted class membership probabilities, assessed through [proper scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info). (b) Once you have that model, [tune one or more decision thresholds by explicitly modeling decision costs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score#F%CE%B2_score